# Regexp capturing crashes the code

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to figure out how regex in c++ works so I've did this example where I try different regexp and see if they match or not:

```
#include <regex>

int main(){

    while (true) {
        string needle;
        cin >> needle;
        regex regexp(needle);
        std::smatch smatch;
        string haystack = "caps.caps[0].MainFormat[0].Video.BitRateOptions = 896, 1536";

        bool match = regex_search(haystack, smatch, regexp);

        if (match) {
            cout << "Matched" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Mismatch" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

```
caps.caps[0].MainFormat[0].Video.BitRateOptions
Mismatch
(caps.caps[0].MainFormat[0].Video.BitRateOptions)
Mismatch
caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions
Matched
(caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions)
Matched
caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions=
Mismatch
(caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions=)
Mismatch
caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions =
Matched
Matched
(caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions =)
THIS ONE BREAK THE PROCESS AND ENDS
caps.caps\[0]
THIS ONE BREAK THE PROCESS AND ENDS
```

Why `caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions =` returns two matches and why capturing this regex crashes the code? Based on this I assume that when I want to match '[' or ']' I need to escape it, and maybe there are some other cases where wrongly constructed regexp might crash the process. Is there any option that will handle unescaped '[' or ']' and other wrong regexp so the code will not crash but rather mismatch? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. Thanks

Comment: Without seeing your regex pattern, I don't think this can be answered.

Comment: My regex patterns are shown in last code snippet - I've tried various regexp patterns and some of them crashed the code as you can see.

Comment: It might be a problem that is related to C++ regex in VS, Here, [it works well](https://ideone.com/2LQbl8).

Comment: See also https://benc45.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/performance-killer-debug-iterator-support-in-visual-studio/, you might want to switch to the Release mode.

Answer (score 2):

The first one

> caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions =

returns two matches, because [`std::cin >> needle;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) reads only until the first whitespace character is found (first match). Then it reads the next "word" `=`, which gives the second match.

---

Similar behaviour happens with the next one

> (caps\.caps\[0\]\.MainFormat\[0\]\.Video\.BitRateOptions =)

The first part is read `(...` excluding the first whitespace. Now the regular expression is incomplete and an exception is thrown.
With g++ this looks like

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
>     what():  regex_error

---

If you want the complete line, use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, needle)) {
// ...
}
```

---

I cannot reproduce any abort with the final one

> caps.caps\[0]

This returns a match as expected.